# bash mapfile NUL bug?

Tags: bash, null

bash's `mapfile` seems to be broken when handling NUL separated input.  In particular, it isn't handling minus characters (`-`) correctly, treating the empty string after one as an end-of-line marker.

For example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

mkdir /tmp/junk
cd /tmp/junk

touch a.txt b.txt c.txt d-e-f.txt
declare -a files

echo "mapfile using default \\n delimiter"
mapfile -t  files < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt')
typeset -p files

echo
echo "mapfile using NUL delimiter"
mapfile -d'' -t  files < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -print0)
typeset -p files

echo
echo "and again"
mapfile -d$'\0' -t  files < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -print0)
typeset -p files
```

```
$ ./test.sh 
mapfile using default \n delimiter
declare -a files=([0]="./d-e-f.txt" [1]="./a.txt" [2]="./c.txt" [3]="./b.txt")

mapfile using NUL delimiter
declare -a files=([0]="./d-" [1]="e-" [2]="f.txt")

and again
declare -a files=([0]="./d-" [1]="e-" [2]="f.txt")
```

Is this a bug? Or am I forgetting something important and just doing it wrong?

The mapfile entry in `man bash` says:

> `-d` The  first  character  of delim is used to terminate each input line, rather than newline.  **If delim is the empty string, mapfile will terminate a line when it reads a NUL character**.

bash version is `5.1.8(1)-release`:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.8(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

---

###### Update

Even weirder, it seems to be mangling existing elements of the array (as shown above) if it already exists, but not even creating it if it doesn't.

```bsh
$ unset files
$ mapfile -t -d'' files < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -print0)
$ typeset -p files
-bash: typeset: files: not found
```

Comment: Note the order of the `-d` and `-t` options in your last example is swapped from the earlier. Swapping them makes your last code work like the earlier examples.  In all your examples, you use no space between `-d` and its argument. Try using a space too and you will find your issue (`mapfile` seems particular in the way it parses its options) and this should tell you why the `-` character in the data behaves like it does too.  It's too hot here to write it up as a proper answer with examples. I'll do that tonight if nobody else steps up.

Comment: yeah, i know they're swapped.  I was testing to see if that makes any difference (in case it was the `-` from `-t` triggering the problem).   Either way, it's a bug, order of options shouldn't make a difference.  and the presence/absence of space between option and option arg shouldn't be significant, either.

Comment: now that i think about it, i'm pretty sure i've run into this before.

Comment: It's only the required space that is the bug (if it is a bug). The issue with the order of the options follows from that.

Comment: if it's not documented, it's definitely a bug.  if it is documented then.....it's still a bug but at least it's documented :)

Comment: OK...and the NULs from find -printf are why `b.txt`, `c.txt`, and `d` aren't in files[0] - bash vars can't contain NUL characters....but with `\n` separators, I'd get `files[0]=$'./a.txt\n./b.txt\n./c.txt\n./d'`

Comment: How would you, as a programmer, detect the nul option argument if it wasn't its own separate argument (I. e. with a space on the command line)? It isn't possible.  About your last comment: What command did that?

Comment: 1. I wouldn't, it's not possible with C strings. So it should be very clearly documented.  2. `mapfile -t -d - files < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' | sort)` (and several variations on the theme produce the same result).   In contrast, `mapfile -d'' -t files < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | sort -z)` gets `files=([0]="./a.txt" [1]="e-" [2]="f.txt")`

Comment: Strictly speaking, the synopsis for `mapfile` in the manual says `mapfile [-d delim]  ...`, i.e. with a space between `-d` and _delim_, so using it like `mapfile -d$'\n'` or `mapfile -d:` or whatever could be construed as misuse. But it's the usual behaviour for option-arguments: if there's characters after the option character, they're taken as the opt-arg, if not, the next arg is taken. Reminds me of the thing that FreeBSD sed needs `sed -i '' -e ...` to not give a suffix for the backup file, instead of just `sed -i -e ...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [bash manual section on Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting):

> Explicit null arguments (`""` or `''`) are retained and passed to commands as empty strings. [...] the word `-d''` becomes `-d` after word splitting and null argument removal.

It's helpful to have an `args` shell script in your toolbox to troubleshoot argument processing. Here's one possible implementation:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
printf "%d args:" "$#"
test "$#" -gt 0 && printf " <%s>" "$@"
echo

# Source:
# https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2021-07/msg00044.html
```

Try it with `mapfile -d'' -t files`:

```
$ args mapfile -d'' -t files
4 args: <mapfile> <-d> <-t> <files>
```

We see that the NUL we thought we were passing to the `-d` option is not present. The argument to the `-d` option is the next argument on the command line: `-t`!

The documentation of `-d` option to `mapfile` [[link]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-mapfile) says:

> The first character of *delim* is used to terminate each input line

The first character of `-t` is `-`.

Thus these two invocations are equivalent:

```
mapfile -d'' -t files
mapfile -d '-' files
```

This explains the result you experienced.

Comment: Also, `mapfile -t -d'' files < ...` is the same as `mapfile -t -d files < ..`, where the delimiter as taken to be `f`, the rest of the string `files` is ignored, and the result is stored in the default array `MAPFILE`.